# Sqlalchemy: Filter how many instances there should be in a relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

If you would want to filter a table by the length of one of its relationships (the number of rows, which exists in a relationship), how would you do that?
I want the filter statement to function like this:

```
Table.query.filter(Table.relationship.length == relationship_length)
```

Here's an example of application:

```
Family.query.filter(Family.children.length == amount_of_children)
```

As stated by Tim Roberts, the way to do it in plain SQL would be:

```
GROUP BY familyid HAVING count(*) > length
```

If there isn't any function for that in sqlalchemy, how can it be done then?

Comment: So, are you saying there is a "Person" table somewhere with a family ID, and you want to know which family IDs have more than N rows?

Comment: Yes. I want to return Families with a specific amount of children.

Comment: In SQL, that'd be a grouped query on the Person table, `GROUP BY familyid HAVING count(*) > length`.  I'm not sure how to express that in SqlAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Tim Roberts, the way to do it in plain SQL would be:

```
GROUP BY tableid HAVING count(*) > length
```

In sqlalchemy, that would be written like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
Table.query.join(Table.relationship).group_by(Table.id).having(func.count() == relationship_length)
```

And for the example, searching for a family with a specific amount of children:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
Family.query.join(Family.children).group_by(Family.id).having(func.count()==amount_of_children)
```